# How to apply slicing window to transform pandas to 2D array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following DataFrame:

```
y =
    1
    3
    1
    4
    2
    5
    1
```

I need to apply a slicing window and transform this DataFrame into a numpy array as follows:

```
array([
        [ 1, 3, 1, 4 ],
        [ 3, 1, 4, 2 ],
        [ 1, 4, 2, 5 ],
        [ 4, 2, 5, 1 ]
     ]
```

Each row contains the 4 sequential values from `y`. The last 3 rows are not included because they would include NaNs.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [`np.as_strided()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

y = pd.Series([1,3,1,4,2,5,1])
y_arr = y.to_numpy()
z_arr = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
  x = y_arr, 
  shape = (4,4), 
  strides = (y_arr.strides[0], y_arr.strides[0])
)

print(z_arr)
[[1 3 1 4]
 [3 1 4 2]
 [1 4 2 5]
 [4 2 5 1]]
```

BEWARE - some of the elements in `z_arr` are actually referencing the same memory block (so you probably want to use `z_arr.copy()`)

[Here's a neat example explaining how this works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJXg0Qi6b3Q)

Comment: Nice, thanks. Maybe you also now how to quickly roll `z_arr` back to `y_arr`?

Comment: You can combine the first column of `z_arr` with the last row of `z_arr` (kind of).  `np.hstack((z_arr[:-1,0], z_arr[-1]))`

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use simple list comprehension with casting to NumPy `ndarray`:

if `y` is a `DataFrame`:

```
np.array([y[k:k+4] for k in range(4)])[:,:,0]
```

if `y` is a `Series`:

```
np.array([y[k:k+4] for k in range(4)])
```

Comment: That's because you probably were using a ```pd.Series``` and not a ```pd.DataFrame``` as stated in question. See my updated answer